# Reading from a text file web2py

Tags: python, file, web2py

I'm having an issue with web2py. I have a text file called defVals.txt that's in the modules folder. I try to read from it, using `open("defVals.txt")` (in a Module in the same director as defVals.txt), but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/jordan/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 212, in restricted
   exec ccode in environment
File "/home/jordan/web2py/applications/randommotif/controllers/default.py", line 67,     in <module>
 File "/home/jordan/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 188, in <lambda>
self._caller = lambda f: f()
File "/home/jordan/web2py/applications/randommotif/controllers/default.py", line 13, in index
  defaultData = parse('defVals.txt')
File "applications/randommotif/modules/defaultValParser.py", line 6, in parse
 lines = open(fileName)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'defVals.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong? Where should I place defVals.txt

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10

Thanks,

Jordan

Update:

This is the source code to defaultValParser.py:

```
import itertools
import string
import os
from gluon import *
from gluon.custom_import import track_changes; track_changes(True)

#this returns a dictionary with the variables in it.
def parse(fileName):
    moduleDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('defaultValParser.py'))
    filePath = os.path.join(moduleDir, fileName)
    lines = open(filePath, 'r')
    #remove lines that are comments. Be sure to remove whitespace in the beginning and end of line
    real = filter(lambda x: (x.strip())[0:2] != '//', lines)
    parts = (''.join(list(itertools.chain(*real)))).split("<>")
    names = map(lambda x: (x.split('=')[0]).strip(), parts)
    values = map(lambda x: eval(x.split('=')[1]), parts)
    return dict(zip(names, values))
```

It works fine if I import it and call it from a terminal (provided I comment out the gluon imports), but if I call it from a web2py controller, it fails completely:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jordan/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 212, in restricted
   exec ccode in environment
  File "/home/jordan/web2py/applications/randommotif/controllers/default.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "/home/jordan/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 188, in <lambda>
  self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/home/jordan/web2py/applications/randommotif/controllers/default.py", line 17, in index
  defaultData = parse('defVals.txt')
  File "applications/randommotif/modules/defaultValParser.py", line 6, in parse
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'defVals.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an absolute path based on the `__file__` path of the module:

```
moduledir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__'))

# ..
defaultData = parse(os.path.join(moduledir, 'defVals.txt'))
```

`__file__` is the filename of the current module, using the `.dirname()` of that gives you the directory the module is in. I used `.abspath()` to make sure you have an absolute path for your module file at all times, heading off some edgecases you could hit otherwise.

`moduledir` is a global in your module.

Comment: The parse function now works fine if I call it from a terminal. But if I call it from a web2py controller, it still fails. I'm going to post the (updated) source code for defaultValParser.py, and the errors that I'm getting.

Comment: @JordanForce: You didn't use my answer :-) Use `__file__` and place `moduledir` at the global level. I did *not* mean for you to replace `__file__` with the filename of the module, `__file__` is an actual python variable assigned to modules.