# i am confused with PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have problem with this command any one can describe it to me !

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

and I want to use to refer to specific file

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('C://Python27//the dataset//h messages' + '/ham'
```

and

```
'C://Python27//the dataset//s messages ' + '/spam'))
```

I don't know if I can use it like this or not ? and what is the right way 
and thank you

Comment: See this previous answer of mine for the first part: [Reading from a text file web2py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015128/14015140#14015140)

Answer (score 0):

```
The __file__ variable contains the path to the current module. The Python documentation can explain the function of os.path.abspath() and os.path.dirname().
```

BTW, you don't need to escape forward slashes in strings, and concatenation here is completely pointless.  The correct way to reference your path would either be:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('C:\\Python27\\the dataset\\h messages\\ham'))
```

or:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('C:/Python27/the dataset/h messages/ham'))
```

Use the same sort of idea for your spam path.

Comment: James Scholes OK I hope I can say thank you but you didn't mention any thing that will help me :p

Comment: And you didn't ask a specific question or mention what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok my question is I want to use this command PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
but I want to replace the __file__ variable with my paths ?